# Flask Login: User.is_anonymous() is a function, but current_user.is_anonymous is an attribute. Why?

Tags: flask, flask-login

This is my first time using flask-login, and I need to support anonymous users.  Authenticated users will have special privileges.  My User model implements its own version of the UserMixin functions; the relevant part is:

```
    def is_authenticated(self):
        """Return True if the user is authenticated."""
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        """If you're not authenticated, you're anonymous."""
        return not self.authenticated
```

Some templates will have code like the following:

```
{% if current_user is not defined or current_user.is_anonymous %}
...render HTML 1
{% else %}
...render HTML 2
{% endif %}
```

This works fine for anonymous users, but authenticated users will also see HTML 1 because `current_user.is_anonymous` evaluates to `<bound method User.is_anonymous of <User *email-address*>`.  Meanwhile, if I change the condition to `current_user.is_anonymous()`, that will throw an error for anonymous users ("TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable").  My understanding is that the User Model needs `is_anonymous` to be a function, but its a Boolean attribute of `current_user`.  This inconsistency is kind of irritating, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

What is the best way to correctly check to see if a user is anonymous?

EDIT:  This is my `user_loader`:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    if user_id is not None:
        return User.query.filter_by(email=user_id).first()
    
    return None
```

EDIT 2:  I removed my custom context processor bc I learned that `LoginManager` provides one for me.  Still, the problem persists. In my templates, `current_user.is_anonymous` still evaluates to `<bound function...`.

Comment: In flask-login source code, `UserMixin(object).is_anonymous` is a property (decorated with @property). Maybe yours needs too, to behave the same for authenticated/anynoumous users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Victor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515831/victor) is correct; I was missing the `@property` decorator.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks Victor!